# openweathermap API doesn't change the local time for the desired city

Tags: android

The time does not change when I change the city location where everything else does. The sunrise and the sunset are changing to the California time in the U.S. I want the time to change to the local time of the city I specify.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
JSONObject main = jsonObj.getJSONObject("main");
JSONObject sys = jsonObj.getJSONObject("sys");
JSONObject wind = jsonObj.getJSONObject("wind");
JSONObject weather = jsonObj.getJSONArray("weather").getJSONObject(0);
Long updatedAt = jsonObj.getLong("dt");
String updatedAtText = "Updated at:   " + new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY   hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH).format(updatedAt * 1000);
Long sunrise = sys.getLong("sunrise");
Long sunset = sys.getLong("sunset");
sunrised.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH).format(new Date(sunrise * 1000)));
sunsetted.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH).format(new Date(sunset * 1000)));`
```

Comment: the code snippet you pasted is not much helpful in debugging the issue you are facing. It could be in one of the network calls or maybe in updating the UI. Its not possible to tell without taking a look at that code. Can you share an online git repo of your code ?